# multiple condition grouping and counting pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I am going to try to express this problem in the most general way possible. Suppose I have a pandas dataframe with multiple columns `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']`.

For each unique value in 'A', I need to get the following ratio: the number of times `'B' == x`, divided by the number of times `'B' == y`, when `'C' == q OR p`...

I'm sorry, but I don't know how to express this pythonically.

Sample data:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'zar', 'zar', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar','foo', 'bar', 'tar', 'foo', 'foo'],
'B': ['one', 'two', 'four', 'three', 'one', 'two', 'three','two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
'C': np.random.randn(11),'D': np.random.randn(11)})`
```

I need something like the following. For each unique value `i` in `'A'`, I need the ratio of the number of times `'B' == 'one'` over the number of times `'B' == 'two'` when `'C' > 2`.

So, an output would be something like:
`foo = 0.75`

Comment: please include a sample data and expected data along with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I multiplied `np.random.randn(11)` by 10 so that the `C > 2` constraint can exist, since `np.random.randn(11)` returns decimal values. The following code will produce what you want in steps. Feel free to condense. Also, it was ambiguous whether the `C > 2` constraint applies to both the numerator and denominator or just the denominator. I assumed just the denominator. If you need it to be applied to the numerator, add the `[df.C > 2]` constraint to the `n` variable as well. Also, the ratios returned for this current df are `inf` if divide by 0 occurs and `nan` if 0 divided by 0 occurs.

```
for i in df.A.unique():
    #print unique value
    print(f"Unique Val: {i}")

    #print numerator
    print("Numerator:")
    n = (df[df.A == i].B == 'one').sum()
    print(n)

    #print denominator
    print("Denominator:")
    d = (df[df.A == i][df.C > 2].B == 'two').sum()
    print(d)

    #print ratio
    print("Ratio:")
    r = n/d
    print(r, "\n")
```

Comment: This is a nice solution. Thank you.